# I dont see how its possible to explain why these logical connectives is adequate

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

"Explain why {$\wedge$, $\perp$} is adequate". I translate this to:

Show how to construct {$\vee$, $\implies$, $\neg$} using only {$\wedge$, $\perp$}.

I know that I can show this by comparing truth tables for each. But I dont see how I can get $T$ from other than $p \wedge q$ when $p = T$ and $q = T$.

But since $\perp$ is "defiend" as $F$ (right?) then how can i get $T$ by using only $\wedge$?

Since $F \wedge (T \vee F)$ is always $F$ (false and whatever else is always false)

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the question? The set $\{ \wedge,\perp\}$ isn't adequate. See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness

Comment: More precisely, $\land$ and $\bot$ are both falsity-preserving (as well as monotonic). On the other hand $\{{\land},{\neg}\}$ is complete.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You should give that as an answer.